# docker-py: container STDIN and STDOUT

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to create run a containerized application using docker-py, and I need to write input data to its STDIN, and read from its STDOUT. Basically this kind of workflow

```
echo "hello" | docker run -i --rm busybox sh -c "cat -"
```

but in Python. In short, I've tried the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843625/how-to-send-to-stdin-of-a-docker-py-container) for the STDIN part, and  [attached another socket](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach_socket) for the STDOUT part. But it does not work as well as I hoped... Here is a minimal example:

`docker_test.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import docker

client = docker.DockerClient()
container = client.containers.run(
    auto_remove=True,
    command="cat -",
    detach=True,
    image="busybox",
    stdin_open=True,
)

# Writing to stdin
input_socket = container.attach_socket(
    params={
        "stdin":True,
        "stream":True,
    },
)
with open("test.txt") as file:
    input_socket._sock.send(file.readline().encode("utf-8"))

# Reading from stdout
output_socket = container.attach_socket(
    params={
        "stdout":True,
        "stream":True,
        "logs":True,
    },
)
for line in output_socket:
    print(line.decode())
```

a dummy `test.txt`

```
1
2
3
4
```

and the result of the execution:

```
$ ./docker_test.py                                                                                                             
1
```

As you can see, it only outputs the first line of the test file, followed by a bunch of newlines, and hangs. Sometimes, it doesn't output anything at all, but in either case, it never exits.

How do I do this correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you just need to sys.stdout.flush()